# Google could zone delete and extra fees

Tags: google-app-engine, debian, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm not sure if you faced the same issue as mine , but i learned form Google that whether i have running instances or disks on specific zones or not. all zones added to specific project still i'm going to be charged

so i do have long list of zones added to my project (which is not used) and i want to delete them (attached)[Number of zones need to be deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L1ni.png)

I'm running a Gcloud command to retrieve or delete any of the zones with Project owner account and i keep receive the issue "Insufficient Permission" and i'm the project owner[Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM3ty.png)

I'm not sure what exactly the problem ? any one can help ?

Thanks
Mohamed

Comment: Where did you learn you're being charged for zones? I'm pretty sure you should be charged only for resources you create (instances, disks, ...) and network traffic you generate.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing Cloud DNS zones and Compute Engine resources in its availability zones.

On your first screenshot you're referring to 1 disk and 1 instance live in `us-central1-f` zone and I suspect that these resources are related to the instance `stitch-vm` that you're logged into on your second screenshot.

You might not be able to access Cloud DNS zones via `gcloud` because you never activated Cloud DNS API in the first place. Provide what you see from Cloud Console [Cloud DNS](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/dns/zones) section.

Comment: Hello There..here is what in the Cloud DNS:tried to provide image but im not able to do so.

us-central1-f
DNS name:comashi.com. A zone
Record sets
DNS name:comashi.com.  
Type:NS 
TTL (seconds):21600
Data  
ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
 
DNS name:comashi.com.  SOA  21600  
ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300

Comment: So you should be able to delete that zone from this screen in Cloud Console if that's what you're after.